# How to uninstall without the usual button?

Tags: google-play-store, settings, uninstallation, verizon, application-manager

A bunch of apps that I do not want and did not install, mainly games, have appeared on my Samsung Galaxy 71 5G, UI 5.1, Android 13, not jailbroke. Settings shows them as installed by the Verizon app manager. The Verizon app manager shows as installed by itself. When you go to settings apps manage, none of these apps have the normal uninstall button. When you go to Google Play manage apps, None of these apps appears at all, even the ones that are available on the Play Store (e.g. Candy Crush)

I do not know how to uninstall an app without the standard tool. Is there some uninstaller app or other tool that will let me do this? You should assume that I am not very sophisticated, e.g. I have not jailbreaked (jailbroken?) my phone for fear of bricking it.

Comment: Some manufacturers and carriers pre-install "bloatware," software that is unwanted and sometimes can't be removed by the user. If there is a "Disable" button in the settings you can use that to remove it from your app drawer, home screen, etc., although it will still technically occupy storage space on your device.